# Interrupt On GAS

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler, intel-syntax

I'm trying to convert my simple program from Intel syntax to the AT&T(to compile it with GAS). I've successfully converted a big part of my application, but I'm still getting an error with the `int`(the interrupts). My function is like this:

```
printf:
    mov $0x0e, %ah
    mov $0x07, %bl

    nextchar:
       lodsb
       or %al, %al
       jz return
       int 10
       jmp nextchar

    return:
       ret

msg db "Welcome To Track!", 0Ah
```

But when I compile it, I got this:

> hello.S: Assembler messages:
>   hello.S:13: Error: operand size mismatch for `int'
>
>   hello.S:19: Error: no such instruction:`msg db "Hello, World!",0Ah'

What I need to do?

Comment: The child in me read the title in a way you probably did not intend :)

Answer (score 7):

In `GAS`, constants need a `$`.  Change that line to:

```
int $10
```

And your message should be:

```
msg: .byte "Welcome to Track!", 0x0a
```

Or even better:

```
msg: .asciiz "Welcome to Track!\n"
```

Comment: Now what I got was this: `hello.S:19: Error: bad expression - 
hello.S:19: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is H`

Comment: @Nathan, You didn't write what I put down then.  You left the 'h' on the end of that line.  `h` is not a hexadecimal digit, so it chokes trying to parse it.

Comment: @Carl: Of course I did, it's this: `msg: .byte "Welcome to Track!", 0x0A`, but I got that error! **:(**

Comment: There is an `H` there somewhere or it wouldn't be giving you that error.

Comment: @Carl: Sorry, my bad, in the error, it's `W` not `H`, but what I think is that the problem is on the first letter of the sentence(inside the quotes)...

Comment: @Nathan, your assembler must have different syntax than mine, then.  Go check its manual for more details.

Comment: But, it's GAS. Anyway, +1 for you to at least try to help me. **:)**

Comment: @Nathan, mine is GAS too.  Just clearly not the same version/variety as yours.

Comment: I would also suggest using `.asciz`. I didn't see anyone bring it up but I think the OP is trying to use teletype output via the BIOS. It should be `int $0x10` and not `int $10` (the former being hex and the latter decimal)