# ASM: operand size mismatch for 'out' error

Tags: assembly, att

I'm a beginner in ASM programming and I'm trying to read the PIT count. However the following code generates the error: "operand size mismatch for 'out'". (I'm using AT&T syntax)

```
movb $0b00000100, %al
outb %al, 0x43
```

How can I solve it? 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually not, al is the source and 0x43 is the destination port.

Problem solved! The following code works: 
outb %al, $0x43

Comment: Well then, answer your own question and accept, or close the question altogether.

Comment: Unfortunately, users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931224/interrupt-on-gas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code works:

```
outb %al, $0x43
```

Thanks.